# How to make any row fixed at the bottom of screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make this highlighted row fixed at the bottom of the screen in flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use bottom app bar to make appbar at the bottom of screen. It is also fixed at the bottom of screen.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    child: new Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    ),
    color: Colors.blueGrey,
  ),
```

[image: Result of above code]

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a fixed row at the bottom, you can use `bottomSheet` like so,

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Test'),
            ),
            body: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('')
                  )
                  ),
          bottomSheet: Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            height: 100.0,
            child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                    child: Container(
                        height: 70.0,
                        child: FlatButton(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.grey,),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        )
                    )
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 70.0,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket, color: Colors.grey,),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      )
                    )
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 70.0,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        child: Text('Checkout', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      )
                    )
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
            )
            );
  }

}
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]